# overflow scroll breaks in nested grid

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

I have two CSS-Grids. One within the other. I don't want the whole page to scroll, but only the contents of a grid-area of the nested grid. This nested grid should fill all available space. However `overflow:scroll` does not work within this nested grid.

As you can see in the simplified example below, the div with the class `.aside` works perfectly while the div with `.bottomleft` does not scroll at all.

The div-heights start to break with the `.main-container` - div, but I have no idea why.

What really confuses me is why everything works fine in the `.aside` - div. The only difference that I can see here is that it is not in the nested grid.

Naturally, everything works perfectly if the `.bottom-left` - div or the second row of the `.main-container` - grid are given a fixed height, but the goal is to make it variable.

I also tried adding various `max-heights` and `heights` to other parent divs, but was not successful so far.

Thank you!

https://jsfiddle.net/vs6c4gq9/3/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#root {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'nav nav ' 'aside main';
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: lightpink;
  height: 100%;
}

.aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'topleft topright' 'bottomleft bottomright';
  height: 100%;
  
}

.topleft {
  grid-area: topleft;
}

.topright {
  grid-area: topright;
}

.bottomleft {
  grid-area: bottomleft;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
}

.bottomright {
  grid-area: bottomright;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="main-container">
        <div class="topleft">
          topleft
        </div>
        <div class="topright">
          topright
        </div>
        <div class="bottomleft">
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>

          <div>last</div>

        </div>
        <div class="bottomright">
          bottomright
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aside">
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>last</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in the sense that there doesn't seem to be any reason why the scroll function works on one element (`.aside`), but not on another (`.bottomleft`). There doesn't appear to be any material difference. One element is a nested grid container. But that shouldn't matter.

However, if you look at the bigger picture, *neither scrollbar should work*.

The `overflow` property normally requires a fixed length to generate a scroll bar. Without such a limit, the element simply expands to accommodate content, and there's no possibility for an overflow.

Such is the case in your code: Both overflow elements are set to `height: auto`.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto; <-- second row (where 'aside' is placed) is
                                     set to content-based height
  grid-template-areas: 'nav nav ' 'aside main';
  height: 100%;
}

.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto; <-- second row (where 'bottomright' is placed) is
                                     also set to content-based height
  grid-template-areas: 'topleft topright' 'bottomleft bottomright';
  height: 100%;
}
```

Now refer to this rule, as described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or `white-space` set to `nowrap`.

Hence, the scroll function in your code should fail in both cases. The fact that one works in at least one browser suggests an anomaly or an [intervention](https://github.com/WICG/interventions). In either case, I would suggest it's unreliable.

Consider a trade-off: Sacrifice some flexibility in return for more stability and security. Here is a modified version of your code:

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b24kcwmy/)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 25px calc(100vh - 25px); /* adjustment */
  grid-template-areas: 'nav nav ' 'aside main';
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

.aside {
  grid-area: aside;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.main-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 25px calc(100vh - 50px);  /* adjustment */
  grid-template-areas: 'topleft topright' 'bottomleft bottomright';
}

.topleft {
  grid-area: topleft;
}

.topright {
  grid-area: topright;
}

.bottomleft {
  grid-area: bottomleft;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.bottomright {
  grid-area: bottomright;
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* remove default margins */
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      header
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="main-container">
        <div class="topleft">
          topleft
        </div>
        <div class="topright">
          topright
        </div>
        <div class="bottomleft">
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>
          <div>bottomleft</div>

          <div>last</div>

        </div>
        <div class="bottomright">
          bottomright
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aside">
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>aside</div>
      <div>last</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about those interventions. That would explain this behaviour. Your solution is still quite flexible, so I'll go with that, thank you!